# Why MultiSelectionHelper with Form View DataSource doesn't stop?

Tags: forms, grid, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I'm using `MultiSelectionHelper, my code is this :

```
MyView currentRecord;
MultiSelectionHelper helper = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();
helper.parmDatasource(MyView_ds);

currentRecord = _helper.getFirst();

while (currentRecord)
{
   // to do action
   currentRecord= helper.getNext();
}
```

But the problem in *while* loop not stop when see in Debug *currentRecord.RecId = 0 , map = Common*

The cycle don't stop, and continue without record!

Comment: You have `_helper` and `helper`. Is this a typo or a bug?

Comment: `MultiSelectionHelper` does record caching. You can try moving your code to/from the client or server and/or restarting your AOS and clearing your user caches.

Comment: Hi @ Alex Kwitny, thanks, I moved my code in Form's active method, add `while(currentRecord.RecId)` .

Comment: It seems odd to have this code in a form's active method. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but I would think there's another way. I suspect your issue may have been due to the location of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to change your while condition like the following:

```
MyView currentRecord;
MultiSelectionHelper helper = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();
helper.parmDatasource(MyView_ds);

currentRecord = _helper.getFirst();

while (currentRecord.RecId != 0)
{
   // to do action
   currentRecord= helper.getNext();
}
```

If this doesn't work please refresh the cache and data from tools menu. This will surely solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Numan Ijaz I moved the code in dataSource Form's active method and adding your condition in while loop. Now work. Thanks.